# Cost study comparing Kosher and non Kosher foods

Tags: food, money

Is there any published cost study analysis comparing production costs for Kosher and non Kosher foods?

For example chicken. Non Kosher chicken costs x. Extra Production costs to produce Kosher chicken is y. x+y= actual cost of producing Kosher chicken.

Comment: As I understand the formula is amountPeopleAreWillingToPay-(overhead/unitsProduced+costOfProduction)=profit. If (profit*unitsProduced) >salaryYouCouldHaveMadeSomewhereElse you keep your business. If not, drop it and try something else.

Comment: That explains why Chalav Yisrael is *so* much more expensive when it has not such difficult to achieve certification.

Comment: Am I alone in expressing doubt that this question is not relevant as expressed even though it comes from Gershon Gold?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about economics; not Judaism. It is not even seeking information about some other discipline to facilitate performance of Judasim.